# How do i fix ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I wanted to make a tic-tac-toe game. To make it, I wanted to use the `pygame` library. I installed it with `pip install pygame`. However, when I try to import it in my IDE (pycharm), I get the following message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

When I tried to install it *again*, thinking I did something wrong, I got this message in the terminal:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in...
```

*Has anyone had this problem, and how do I fix it?*

Comment: Is PyCharm using the correct python environment?

Comment: check Project Interpreter in PyCharm, you should add modules there not by using pip or python

Answer (score 1):

If u want to use it on Pycharm u have to go to `File > Settings> Project Interpreter > Click "+" button > Search for pygame and install it`

Doing `pip install XXXX` you are not doing anything, u are using a virtual enviorment (Pycharm)

Comment: Thank you! This worked, do I have to always do this with community-built modules?

Answer (score -1):

Try this if you are on windows :

C:\python34\scripts> python -m pip install pygame